# How to properly use GREP to parse out information from a command in sequential order?

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

This is my first post on here, so please excuse any mistakes. I am new to bash scripting etc. I'm creating a script to do a basic health check on some storage systems. There will be more to the health check other than this command, but I just wanted to figure this out before proceeding further into creating this script.

I'm using the following command to get the information from the system.

```
*> isi status --all-nodes
Node LNN:             1
Node ID:              1
Node Name:            ATLSTOR01-1
Node IP Address:      192.168.4.200
Node Health:           OK
Node SN:              SV200-000NZY-1MYR
Member of Node Pools: simulator_100gb_6gb
Member of Tiers:      n/a
Node Capacity:        56.7G
Available:            55.9G (99%)
Used:                  830M ( 1%)

Network Status:
    See 'isi network interfaces list -v' for more detail or man(8) isi.
internal:            2 GbE network interfaces (2 up, 0 down)
external:            6 GbE network interfaces (1 up, 5 down)
```

I want to parse out Node ID and Node Health from this output. I use the following command to do so:

```
*> isi status --all-nodes | grep ID && isi status --all-nodes | grep Health
Node ID:              1
Node ID:              2
Node ID:              3
Node ID:              4
Node Health:           OK
Node Health:           OK
Node Health:           OK
Node Health:           DEGRADED
```

Is there any way to make the output look like this:

```
Node ID:              1
Node Health:           OK
Node ID:              2
Node Health:           OK
Node ID:              3
Node Health:           OK
Node ID:              4
Node Health:           DEGRADED
```

Thanks for any help that is provided.

Comment: `isi status --all-nodes | grep -E 'Node ID:|Node Health:'`

Comment: Are you sure you want the output to look like that and not a series of ID-Health pairs like `1 OK<newline>2 OK`, etc. or something? If you'd prefer some other output format then don't change this question, accept an existing answer then ask a new question since you already have answers to the question as asked.

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting solution with `grep`:

```
isi status --all-nodes| grep -E "^Node (ID|Health):"
```

Suggesting solution with `awk`:

```
isi status --all-nodes| awk '/^Node (ID|Health):/{print}'
```

Comment: You don't need `{print}` in the awk command as that's the default action given a true condition, just like in grep.